# What ML package (RNN model) has the capacity to predict with data of less time steps than training data

Tags: machine-learning, package, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

(Since [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280766/predict-using-data-with-less-time-steps-different-dimension-using-keras-rnn-mo) is probably not getting an answer because of too specific about one package, I will ask another general.)

According to the RNN Model, we have an input and output for every step. Let's say a model trained with data of 6 time steps. Of course if I use test data of 6 time steps, I will get outputs, and I have succeed in that. But theoretically, if I only have data of first 3 time steps, I should get an output from the 3rd output node too (without re-train a model with first 3 time steps). But I found at least "keras" package can't do this.

Is there any packages that support such prediction? Better in python language and better to have LSTM layer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem you have two options, depending on your goal.

1. You can pad sequences in the end with zeros so they are the correct dimension but in the output you just use the first `n` steps according to your test data dimension.
2. You can use a stateful implementation